# Angular 5 Get reference inside ng-template

Tags: angular

I have something like this :

```
<div class="row">
  <ng-template #filtersTemplate let-sidenavFilter="sidenavFilter">
    <div class="row flex mt-md-5">
      <canvas #barChart id="canvasStacked">{{ chart }}</canvas>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</div>


<fn-filter [filters]="filters" [responsive]="false" [template]="filtersTemplate" (onSubmit)="search($event)"></fn-filter>
```

Is it possible to get a reference to #barChart? @ViewChild does not work due to ng-template wrapping the reference.

Comment: You can only get reference after creating embedded view

Comment: Can you explain me a bit more?

Comment: How do you use this template?

Comment: I have update my code. I passed the template to a component that add filters around the canvas.

Comment: Where are you going to use  `#barChart` in parent component or in `fn-filter`?

Comment: In parent component

Comment: See console here https://ng-run.com/edit/pzwtozXQ2095qIckF38w

Comment: Is the fact that you access the reference after fnèfilter component was load, not inside the ngAfterViewInit, that make it work?