# Template reference variable returns undefined inside ng-template

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, ng-template

Already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45677905/angular4-component-reference-inside-ng-template) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49127590/angular-5-get-reference-inside-ng-template) solution but nothing worked.

I am using Angular 7 and trying to get a reference variable which I've placed inside the **ng-template** tag. But it always returns **undefined**

**test-component.html**

```
<ng-template #abc>
  <div #xyz>    
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

**test-component.ts**

```
@ViewChild('abc') abc: ElementRef; //---> works fine
@ViewChild('xyz') xyz: ElementRef; //---> undefined
```

**test-component.ts**

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
  console.log(this.xyz); //---> undefined  
}
```

I've tried printing it in all the life cycle hooks of angular but it always returns undefined. But when I try putting it in out side of **ng-template** it works perfectly.

Is there any way around?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because, the content inside `ng-template` is not yet rendered.

You should first activate it using `ngTemplateOutlet`.

Add the following code in your html, it should work

```
<ng-template #abc>
  <div #xyz>    
  </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="abc"></ng-container>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1pvpdy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you @Amit, It works. But I am using [NgbPopOver] (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples#tplcontent) for a chat module. It messes with the design when I put ng-container at the end. Any idea?

Comment: It seems it just behaves like a simple div when we put ng-container below the ng-template. Am I right?

Comment: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/

Answer (score 4):

The reason it's happening is because of the [ng-template](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#the-ng-template) is never rendering on the **HTML** all by itself.

As per **Angular** docs:

> The **ng-template** is an Angular element for rendering HTML. It is never displayed directly. In fact, before rendering the view, Angular replaces the  and its contents with a comment.

It can be referred to using `ngTemplateOutlet` or when with `*ngIf else` or something like that. It doesn't exist on its own:

**Update:**

```html
<div *ngIf="someConditionCheck;else abc">
  content here ...
</div>

<ng-template #abc>
  <div #xyz></div>
</ng-template>
```

You can find the demo code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a8zmsz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Thank you @Shashank, Can you please tell me more about how to use *ngIf else specifically for this solution?

Comment: @AdnanSheikh It'll work when you put proper condition. Check the demo code